# How to avoid hiding the only line showing?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

When enabling the highcharts legend, it comes with a default functionality: If you click the line in the legend, it will toggle the visibility of the line in the chart.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend

While this feature is nice to have, I never want the user to hide all the lines in the chart, as that's just ugly:

[image]

How can you prevent the last line showing from being hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this method to the chart options:

```
 plotOptions: {

     series: {
         events: {
             legendItemClick: function() {
                 if (this.visible) {

                     // don't hide if it's the only line showing
                     var nShowing = 0;

                     for (var index = 0; index < this.chart.series.length; ++index) {
                         var s = this.chart.series[index];
                         if (s.visible) {
                             nShowing++;
                         }
                     }

                     return (nShowing > 1);
                 }

                 return true;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```